# Why does Authorize attribute not cause HTTP 401 for unauthorized requests with JWTs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt

I have a Web API app that I am hopefully protecting with JWTs as follows, in `Startup`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
            };
        });
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

I also have `app.UseAuthentication();` in the `Startup.Configure` method. When I make an unauthorized request using Postman, I get nothing as a response, just a blank body, and when I allow anonymous on the same action, I get the expected result. I also get the expected result if I make an authorized request. I would expect an HTTP 401 when I make an unauthorized request, not just nothing happening.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure. Perhaps you need to configure the challenge scheme.  Below works for me (.NET Core 2.x).

```
public static IServiceCollection AddJwtValidation(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            IServiceProvider sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            ConfigRoot = sp.GetRequiredService<IConfigurationRoot>();

            tokenAudience = ConfigRoot["JwtToken:Audience"];
            tokenIssuer = ConfigRoot["JwtToken:Issuer"];

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Audience = tokenAudience;
                options.ClaimsIssuer = tokenIssuer;

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {                    
                    // The signing key must match!
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    RequireSignedTokens = true,
                    IssuerSigningKeyResolver = MyIssuerSigningKeyResolver,

                    // Validate the JWT lifetime.  Note that if 'exp' is present, then it is validated.  If it 
                    // is missing, then the lifetime validation is not done.
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    RequireExpirationTime = false,
                    LifetimeValidator = null, //MyLifetimeValidator,

                    // Validate the JWT Issuer (iss) claim
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = tokenIssuer,

                    // Validate the JWT Audience (aud) claim
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = tokenAudience,
                };

                // Override the default ValidateToken method with a custom method.
                options.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();
                options.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new MyJwtSecurityTokenHandler());
            });

        return services;
    }
```